# Errors while building grass-7.0.1 with Msys/MinGW

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I need to build grass-7.0.1 for qgis on Windows 10 with Msys/MinGW. I succefully installed all packages from general and several packages from optional requirements. Here is my `configure` options (minimal):

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--enable-largefile \
--disable-x11 \
--with-cxx \
--with-proj-share=/usr/local/share/proj \
--without-gdal \
--without-x \
--without-sqlite \
--without-postgres \
--disable-doc \
--without-freetype \
--without-cairo \
--without-tiff \
--without-png \
--without-opengl \
--without-fftw \
--without-regex
```

Then I wait about 15 minutes while compiling and get this message:

[image]

```
In case of errors please change into the directory with error and run 'make'.
If you get multiple errors, you need to deal with them in the order they
appear in the error log. If you get an error building a library, you will
also get errors from anything which uses the library.
```

Grass Makefiles contains complex referencing and it's too expensive to try fix the problems one by one. Maybe any ideas?

UPD

Ok, after some experimentation, I realized that this is a problem of [missing demolocation](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/625). But that ticket is outdated, so I still need help. This error occurs during the compilation of all these packages:

```
access: No such file or directory
ERROR: LOCATION </dist.i686-pc-mingw32/demolocation> not available
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the errors you see will be subsequent problems of the first error (or first few errors). Solving the first compilation problem likely solves most of the other errors since the code is compiled in dependency order.

The "demolocation" is included in the source code, so there must be something wrong with the path to it on your machine.

Did you follow this guide? https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/CompileOnWindows

Comment: No, since I tried to build qgis instead of grass itself and taking into account [official recommendations](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc14), I used an outdated step-by-step tutorial by Marco Pasetti. Thank you, now I took the instructions you have provided, and build is successful. But I'm not sure yet that this build is suitable for qgis.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!